# Build Warning : Mapping new ns to old ns

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

So, I'm using Flutter and on running the App, I receive errors like these in the debug console:

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
```

I did `flutter clean`, but no effect.

I tried the answer here:
[How to change build tools version in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951187/how-to-change-build-tools-version-in-android-studio)

But, when I look for *build.gradle* file, I have two files one in */android* and another in */android/app*. But both of these do not have any configuration to change `buildToolsVersion`.

I did `sdkmanager --list_installed` and I hae two *build-tools* versions:

```
  build-tools;29.0.2   | 29.0.2  | Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 | build-tools/29.0.2  
  build-tools;30.0.2   | 30.0.2  | Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 | build-tools/30.0.2
```

What should I do to fix this Warning ?

Also, I am not using Android Studio. I used this guide to install Flutter without Android Studio:
[How to Install and Configure Flutter Without Android Studio](https://superflutter.blogspot.com/2021/08/how-to-install-and-configure-flutter.html)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try deleting and reinstalling the SDK platforms. Delete the folders in ~\Android\Sdk\platforms and download the SDKs you need.

Edit: The above somehow resolved the issue before, but I ran into the same problem again when more external packages were updated. This time, deleting the SDK platforms didn't work. Instead, I updated Gradle in two locations in my project:

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1' // Update this line
        ...
    }
}
```

*Note*: 7.2.1 for the Android Gradle Plugin is the latest stable release present at this time in Google's Maven repository. To check for newer versions, visit https://maven.google.com, or the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin). Under [*com.android.tools.build > gradle*](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.android.tools.build:gradle) you will find the versions available for Android.

**android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip # Update this line
```

Updating the plugin in these two spots resolved the issue for me this time.

Comment: This finally solved my issue after so many searching. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, it seems working for me 

Comment: This can probably be resolved more easily by using the automated tools in Android Studio. If you see a message "Project update recommended: Android Gradle Plugin can be upgraded.", click on it to perform the steps described in this answer automatically.

Answer (score 3):

as per the top-voted answer, the bug not fixed for me.....

so using this way fixed my bug

1. first updated the "android sdk build-tools" to 32

path :android studio>sdk manager>system setting>android sdk>sdk tool> update "android sdk build-tools"

then

android/build.gradle added this line

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
```

then

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

after

"flutter clean" on terminal

restart

i am using flutter 2.8.1 , after that we can see in android/.gradle new file will appear that is 7.0.2 folder

so using this way fixed my bug

Answer (score 1):

It not happen becuase of you have two build-tools version installed. It happens because of caches so on android studio just invalidating caches and restarting will fix this.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I am not using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Please change two files:

1. android/build.gradle and set as the following under dependencies:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'`

2. android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and set the following: Here the Gradle version should be compatible with the mentioned in the build.gradle file.

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while setting up Unreal Engine 5.0.3 to build for Oculus Quest 2. I was getting this error consistently when running SetupAndroid.bat

None of the other answers worked for me.

My solution to this was to <s>(nuke it from orbit)</s> uninstall Android Studio and delete the entire SDK directory.
Then reinstall again and re-download the required SDK packages.

Fixed forever!

Answer (score 0):

Trying between the above answers,
I ran into some problems trying to maintain a project that was created a long time ago.

However, something occurred to me, add the references that are automatically created in the new Flutter projects (v3.7.x) I tried these references in the old project that I had and I was able to skip the errors that appeared in the console and I did not have any more issues.
The changes I made are the following
`/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
....
}
...
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    
...
}
```

in `gradle/wapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score -5):

1.Update gradle plugin as mentioned in the top-voted answer

2.Add `android:exported="true"` inside activity element in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml