# Why is this Warning showing when I try to debug my Flutter application

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-studio, dart

This is not an error, this warning showing when I run or Debugging my app,

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
```

how do I fix and what's the exact problem is this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600352/build-warning-mapping-new-ns-to-old-ns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build Warning : Mapping new ns to old ns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600352/build-warning-mapping-new-ns-to-old-ns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading the gradle wrapper version (`gradle-wrapper.properties`) and the gradle plugin version (`/android/build.gradle`) to the latest ones.

In gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

In /android/build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
```