# running flutter in vs code shows Running with sound null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

This is my first app in flutter using VS Code.

While I try to run my program via terminal using command `flutter run` shows:

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             12.3s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...                9.4s

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

 Running with sound null safety 

An Observatory debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:63186/_rjqXM3bogc=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:63186/_rjqXM3bogc=/
```

After this nothing happens in terminal neither virtual device opens up. What is happening?
When running `flutter doctor` shows everything ok.

Comment: try this  'flutter run --no-sound-null-safety' in vscode terminal

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because of `gradle version` this is an error like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600352/build-warning-mapping-new-ns-to-old-ns) just update your gradle in `Your_Flutter_App > android > build.gradle`, `dependencies` block to new versions like:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
```

check `buildToolsVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` in `/android/app/build.gradle` if didnt work.