# When running flutter getting this warning

Tags: android, flutter

`Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01`

Why this warning is comming and how to solve this?

environment:
sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

compileSdkVersion 33
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 33

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your gradle to the latest version.

Go to `android->build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    
    ...

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0' //update and use latest version
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Please research a little bit before asking a question. Check more solutions and same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600352/build-warning-mapping-new-ns-to-old-ns)